# 360 Total Security and Windows Explorer challenge

Tags: windows, registry, explorer, antivirus

I had a `Windows 8.1` machine running `NOD32` antivirus. After a while, I removed that and installed `360 Total Security` (it's free) and enabled all five engines.
I tried to check windows (with startup and registry check that is does) and after a reboot, my context menu items where all gone. Also I can create a new folder with explorer's toolbox.
When I Googled the error, wasn't a really useful answer that described what can I do to restore  all those items like my graphic control panels and text editors.
So I decided to remove and install a newer version of windows (`Win10`). I have this bug again.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVgHr.png).
My windows wasn't configure to create scheduled backups from `c:` and registry.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go.
After spending time on checking logs for `360 Total Security`, I have found the solution. `Avira AntiVir` engine detected those shortcuts as virus!!! So I just restored it from quarantine and I'm done. [Log file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQL5P.png).